# How to achieve a "pan out" animation on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Let's say the following coordinates are relative to (0, 0) being the top left corner of the phone's screen with increasing positive x values going to the right and increasing positive y values going down as diagrammed here: http://t.cyol.com/cache/temp/img/2011/02/1000/119/img/img_1297675862_0.jpg

I'd like to do a "pan out" animation where there is a little box whose top left corner is at (x, y), and it has width w and height h where x, y, w, and h are greater than 0. Everywhere inside that box is some content. Everywhere outside that box is black.

Over 500 milliseconds, the box's top left corner should move to (0, 0) and its width and height will grow to fill the entire screen. That is, over half a second, the box pans out to fullscreen.

The content inside the box is a WebView.

How do I achieve this animation? I tried scaling, but that's not what I want to achieve, because the content inside the box shouldn't get squished. Translating only works if the box starts out in a corner.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this effect, the whole view must be relayouted at each frame of the animation. You'll need to change the layout params of the view and call `requestLayout()`. Check this link:

[Android Animate Scale Image to fit screen width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186062/android-animate-scale-image-to-fit-screen-width-and-height)