# Animation scale to fit screen width

Tags: android, animation, scale

I need to have an animation that scales a view to the screen width over 1500 seconds.
I haven't got a clue how to achieve this. I searched for an hour now on the internet...

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:toXScale="?"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:fillAfter="false"
     />
</set>
```

The method where the animation gets called:

```
tab1.Click += delegate
        { 
            ResetMenuItem();
            animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(ApplicationContext, Resource.Animation.grow_anim1);
            animation.Duration = duration;

        //  int width = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)ConvertDpToPix(3f),RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
            selector1.LayoutParameters = p;
            selector1.StartAnimation(animation);
            animation.AnimationEnd+=delegate 
            {
                drawer.CloseDrawers();
            };
            tabIndex=1;

        };
```

Comment: What about this? Just edit out the height scaling. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186062/android-animate-scale-image-to-fit-screen-width-and-height?rq=1

Comment: Nevermind i used a thread to edit the width of the view

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by using a thread to edit the width of the view.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and thanks for posting the answer. You might want to go into a little more detail with the final code you used, so other users can benefit from your solution in the future.